# Typescript object is possibly 'undefined' with condition in a variable

Tags: typescript

I use typescript in strict mode and sometime to increase readability or intention, I use a variable to express complex condition.

Sadly when i need to use a prop on an object I have a typescript error

```
type Input = {amount: number}
const getPaymentAmount = (payment?: Input) => {
  // Any compound condition
  const doesPaymentExists = true && payment

  return doesPaymentExists 
    ? payment.amount // Here payment should be defined
    : 0
}
```

You can test in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAhgWwPaJzABcUciOARhAE4C%20AsAFADGecAzigOYTAAKWEDghEAgvkIp0ACjBCRRAPyl4SYAEo0APkzMoUAPSGoYuCChscYAnAAml9nYCWwZ%2032POKO3ggdBYVFgAFEAD2cuDjQoYBpEaAAyRKh5IKJmTxo%20RBo4KF9-QMVQiKioTwMlVIVggDpcWxRjKAAJWmg0kqgOAAsCABsHagKIADNnOAg7SqhSAAZmOiA)

I got the same issue with a typeguard

```
type Input = {amount: number}
const isPayment = (payment?: Input): payment is Input => !!payment
const getPaymentAmount = (payment?: Input) => {
  // Any compound condition
  const doesPaymentExists = true && isPayment(payment)

  return doesPaymentExists 
    ? payment.amount // Here payment should be defined
    : 0
}
```

And of course if we check the object in the condition it works

```
type Input = {amount: number}
const getPaymentAmount = (payment?: Input) => {
  // Any compound condition
  const doesPaymentExists = true && payment

  return doesPaymentExists && payment
    ? payment.amount // It works -_-
    : 0
}
```

Do you know why typescript cannot detect the existence of `payment` object from my `doesPaymentExists` variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [well](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10065) [known](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22341) behavior. You may check other linked issues there aswell.

[Quote](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22341#issuecomment-370579199) from one of the issues:

> I can't find the other duplicates, but we only check syntactically whether isA is a user-defined type guard at the if check (and other syntactic locations). The type predicate return type is really just a boolean in any other context. So oIsA doesn't track any information about the type of o itself.

> We've considered this problem, but it seems fairly complex and expensive to solve in a general way.

I suppose it's not going to change anytime soon. So your third code snippet is the way to go.

Comment: This looks to be [partially fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730) for a future release.